# replacing a shower base

Tags: shower

I am attempting to replace a cracked shower base.

the shower stall sits on top of the base , before I start , I just want to clarify a few things to ensure I am doing it correctly.

what connects the shower stall to the base and also the wall? is it just the sealant, or is there going to be some other attachment?

ITs just a question of how to I remove the shower glass surround so that I can get access to the base.

I dont see any obvious way that the stall attached to the wall, but clearly there is otherwise it would be loose.

So I am just a little unsure of how to go about removing the stall so I can replace the base.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image][image]

Comment: Is this a formed plastic shower stall?  If so, I you're most likely not going to get it out in one piece...  Picture?

Comment: Those are rather vague questions that depend heavily on the products we're discussing. You'll probably need to find the literature for yours and review the installation process. At a minimum, post photos.

Comment: Yes. Please do post pictures so that we all have some context for your questions.

Comment: I have added a couple of images , hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aluminum shower stalls like that often have a pair of channels that mount to the wall, then the panels slip into them. A small screw or other retainer holds them in place. Look for some way to release the panels. You may need to cut a bead of caulk.

The base is probably nailed or screwed through the top flange. You'll see it when you peel the wall panels off the drywall behind it. You'll also need to cut caulk against the floor and elsewhere for the base.